# Unity C# How to move sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to Unity. I am having difficulty in building a FPS shooter. Here is my code in Ammo prefab:

```
public class Ammo : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject obj ;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        obj= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate (obj.transform.forward* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void OnCollision(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.tag != "Player")
            Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

And in FPS:

```
public class FPS : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Ammo;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Instantiate(Ammo, transform.position,transform.rotation);
        }
    }

}
```

But when I shoot the sphere goes in random direction. (It goes up when I look forward). Is there anyone help me. I am absolutely new to Unity.

Comment: Well, you probably want to move the bullet along its *own* forward axis, not the *player's* otherwise you get curving bullets (fire, wait as it travels in that direction, then turn to face left, now the bullet goes left...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bullet doesn't go in random direction. It depends on your player position. First of all you should take forward vector from **players camera** NOT FROM PLAYER. Because you want to shoot the direction you look at (thus the camera).